# Summing the scores of a test

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, the left hand column consisting of questionnaire participants say 1-20. Followed by 10 columns with answers to 10 possible questions.

Lets say question answers range from a-e where a = 1 point and e = 5 points.

What is the easiest and quickest way to sum up everyones score.

I have attempted to use Sumifs, giving a score to each letter (a=1,b=2...), however, can't figure out how I would formulate the sumif.

I have considered VBA to score each question one by one and them sum the total - however I feel this is very long winded.

Example table (You may use '=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,101))' in order to randomise the letters for each question)

```
Questionnaire / Question 1 / Question 2/ ... / Question 10
1                 a            c                d
2                 d            e                b
...               ...          ...              ...
20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(UPPER(B2:K21))-64)
```

In VBA:

```
Total = Evaluate("=SUM(CODE(UPPER(B2:K21))-64)")
```

This is an array formula, and that's why `SUMPRODUCT()` is better on a sheet, but VBA can work with array without entering as array, hence why the `SUM()` works through VBA. It's sheet equivalent would be: `{=SUM(CODE(UPPER(B2:K21))-64)}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula on all responses adjusting A1 to the cell needed.

```
=CODE(UPPER(A1))-64
```

This converts a or A to 1, b or B to 2 etc. This works because the ASCII value of upper case A is 65. Then you can add the values.

Comment: this makes sense, however, I feel this is a long way of solving this as you have to covert each number then sum the row. Would it not be possible to do this in one single cell. i.e some type of long formula